# Internet request works the first time, but not on subsequent requests

Tags: java, android

On the first request it goes to the internet and retrieves the data. When I try it again, it just gives me the data that is already in the inputstream. How do I clear the cached data, so that it does a new request each time?

This is my code:

```
InputStreamReader in = null;
in = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
response = readFully(in);
url.openStream().close();
```

Comment: Don't set object to null then assigns value. Decomposed MSIL explains why

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the URL object each time.

Comment: Thanks.I was using borrowed code and found that the data was being cached, so I got rid of the caching of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URLConnection and explicitly set the caching policy:

```
final URLConnection conn = (URLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a cached copy.
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

See [The Android URLConnection documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches%28boolean%29) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient API might be useful

```
address = "http://google.com"
String html = "";
HttpClient httpClient = DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(address);
BufferedReader in = null;
HttpResponse response = null;
response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String l = "";
String nl = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(l + nl);
}
in.close();
html = sb.toString();
```

You'll need to catch some exceptions

Comment: Thanks.I was using borrowed code and found that the data was being cached, so I got rid of the caching of data.